# Stickman Ragdoll keeps twisting

Tags: unity, rotation

I am very new to game development but I do have some programming experience of a few years, but that isn't helping me. I am trying to create a simple ragdoll character( a stickman) by joining the limbs and the head to the torso using Hinge Joints 2D. I also added a code enabling the Ragdoll to move around by applying a force to his body. When I hit the play button, while falling to the ground( a rectangular sprite), the stickman keeps twisting inwards. All the body parts seem to be twisting clockwise even though the motor is disabled on all of them.
So the Stickman goes from this - [image]

To this-
[image]

I have configured the joints as below - 
The leg joint - 
[image]
The Hand joint - 
[image]
The Head joint - 
[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us how you've configured your joints. Also, it looks like the body is still quite a distance above your platform. Is the platform's collider larger than its visual, or do you have forces/constraints keeping the feet from dropping?

Comment: @DMGregory I just kept the body above the ground to see it fall like a ragdoll. The colliders coincide with the shape of their objects, all of them. I have also not used any forces to keep the feet from dropping. You can see the configuration of the joints in the edited answer.